# How do you build a MongoDB spatial index for GeoJSON geometry?

Tags: spatial-index, mongodb, nosql

I'm attempting to build a spatial index on a collection of features that I created from:

`ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON out.json ...` and then imported into MongoDB (2.6.1).

When I attempt to build a spatial index(`{"features" : "2d"}`), 
I receive this error:

```
Error creating index
WriteConcern detected an error 'geo values must be 'legacy coordinate pairs' for 2d indexes
```

The MongoDB glossary has this for legacy coordinate pairs:

> The format used for geospatial data prior to MongoDB version 2.4. This format stores geospatial data as points on a planar coordinate system (e.g. [ x, y ]).

I don't see how the GeoJSON doesn't meet this spec, since the coordinate pairs are also [x,y].  Is there something else in the legacy coordinate that a Mongo spatial index is expecting?  And if that is the case, does this mean that you can't build a spatial index directly against GeoJSON (*meaning that the geometry JSON has to be modified in some way to make it ingestible by MongoDB*).

Ref:
[What is difference between GeoJSON & Legacy coordinate pairs in terms of mongoDb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20016269/what-is-difference-between-geojson-legacy-coordinate-pairs-in-terms-of-mongodb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GeoJSON geometry has more than just an array of the coordinates, which is all the 2d index is expecting. GeoJSON also contains the type and possibly the coordinate system/projection.

From the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2d/#considerations):

> Do not use a 2d index if your location data includes GeoJSON objects. To index on both legacy coordinate pairs and GeoJSON objects, use a 2dsphere index.

So, use a 2dsphere index instead. But, in order to use a 2dsphere index, you will have to project your data to WGS84, since that is what MongoDB [expects](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/).

Comment: Thanks...my coordinates were *NOT* WGS84 so I wasn't using 2dsphere.